# How to solve Maven JSF project : java: package org.primefaces.model.chart does not exist?

Tags: maven, jsf, primefaces, java-ee-6

this is my first time ever working on JavaEE project. I want to add primefaces so I can use it in a JSF xhtml page. I added the dependency to the Maven file as follows.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

the primefaces got indexed to IntelliJ, and I was able to import it in the java code and on the xhtml page. But when I run WildFly to build and deploy the project I got this error.

```
jee/bravo/web/beans/ResultsBean.java:6:34
java: package org.primefaces.model.chart does not exist
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Why not start with our working Primefaces runnable project that runs with `mvn clean jetty:run`. See: this project: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the line `<scope>compile</scope>`.
It means it will only be available at compile time, but not at runtime. So everything looks OK in IntelliJ (during compile) but it is still missing on the Application Server like WildFly (during runtime).

Comment: That's not quite true for WAR files compile means it will be added to the WAR.

Comment: If the problem still occurs in intellij, deleteing .idea and rebuild the project solve the probelm